# To draw a graph like this, what code do I need?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, circles, tikz-pic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
        \coordinate[label=above left:$A$] (A) at (95:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left:$B$] (B) at (200:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left:$D$] (D) at (-110:1);
        \coordinate[label=below right:$C$] (C) at (-60:1);
        \draw[name path=circ] (0,0) circle (1);
        \path[name path=AC] (A) -- ($(A)!1.2!30:(B)$);
%         \path[name path=AC] (D) -- ($(D)!1.2!-15:(B)$);
%         \path[name intersections={of=AC and circ, by={[label=below right:$C$]C}}];
%         \path[name intersections={of=BD and circ, by={[label=above right:$D$]D}}];
        \draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (B) --  cycle;
        \draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (D) --  cycle;
        \draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (C) --  cycle;
        \draw[line join=bevel] (D) -- (C) --  cycle;
        \draw[line join=bevel] (B) -- (D) --  cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please make your code as complete small document with `\documentclass{...} on the start and `\end{document}` on the and. Also add all necessary `tikzlibraries`.

Comment: `\draw[shorten <=100,shorten >=100] (D) -- (C);`

Comment: Where do write? Thanks

Comment: `tkz-euclide` is perfect for such applications

Comment: Wow, five two-sided regular polygons. ;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle (1);
\node[circle, fill=orange, label=above left  :$A$] (A) at (95:1) {};
        \coordinate[label=below left  :$B$] (B) at (200:1);
        \coordinate[label=below left  :$D$] (D) at (-110:1);
        \coordinate[label=below right :$C$] (C) at (-60:1);
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) ;
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (D) ;
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (C) ;
        \draw[blue,shorten <= -30,shorten >= -30] (D) -- (C);
        \draw[blue] (B) -- (D)  node[midway,above,font=\tiny,color=black]{$\theta_{1}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

compiling it gives

[image]

This is not exactly what you want but you have all the elements in hand to obtain exactly what you want.

Comment: No need to say thanks just approve the answer, if you were helped. This is the way the site works.

Answer (score 8):

A version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path circ;
    pair A,B,C,D;

    circ = fullcircle scaled 8cm;
    A = point   95*8/360 of circ;
    B = point  200*8/360 of circ;
    C = point  -60*8/360 of circ;
    D = point -110*8/360 of circ;

    drawoptions(withcolor 1/3[blue,white]);

    draw circ;
    draw A--B;
    draw A--C;
    draw A--D;

    draw (-1/4)[B,D] -- 5/4[B,D];
    draw (-1/4)[C,D] -- 5/4[C,D];

    drawoptions();

    forsuffixes @=A,B,C,D:
       label("$" & str @ & "$", @ scaled 10/9);
       fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted @ withcolor red+1/2green;
    endfor

    label.urt("$e_1$", 1/2[B,D]);
    label.top("$e_2$", 1/2[C,D]);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

These lines

```
 draw (-1/4)[B,D] -- 5/4[B,D];
 draw (-1/4)[C,D] -- 5/4[C,D];
```

show you one simple way to draw lines "through" two points with Metapost, using the mediation syntax.  In general `f[a,b]` gives you a point on the line through `a` and `b` where `f` is a fraction of the distance from `a` to `b`, so `1/2[a,b]` gives you the mid point, and so on.

But note that you need the parentheses round the negative mediant to stop MP interpreting it as `-(1/4[B,D])` which is not the point you want.  I could also have written

```
draw 5/4[D,B] -- 5/4[B,D];
draw 5/4[D,C] -- 5/4[C,D];
```

to avoid the problem.  More beautiful perhaps but also harder to follow.

The `forsuffixes` loop uses `@` as the loop variable.  The `scaled` trick to position the labels only works because the diagram is centred at the origin.